# Ввод многострочного текста в Python с помощью вставки

Tags: python, строки, текст, ввод, работа-с-текстом

Как выполнить многострочный ввод в Python с помощью Ctrl+V и нажатием ОДИН раз Enter?
Я нашел как сделать многострочный ввод через try - except и ввод пустой строки в конце, но там не учитывается необходимость ввода пустых строк в тексте. Плюс в конце окажется лишняя пустая строка и решение будет неверным.
Нужно ввести текст именно вставкой и одним Enter'ом и превратить его хоть в последовательность, хоть в файл .txt, хоть во что угодно. Дальше я уже обработаю его. Обычная вставка через input() дает обработать только первую строку.
Это для задачи "Арифметическая прогрессия - 2" с acmp.ru. Для C++ это вроде через библиотеку stdio.h решается, но я и в Python еще не особо шарю, так что решение на C++ мне не слишком помогло

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Для решения этой задачи такие сложности не нужны. Читаем данные из `sys.stdin` целиком или построчно, а после ввода в консоль жмем `ctrl-d` в linux или `ctrl-z`, `enter` в windows

Comment: Близко, но нет. Для правильного решения задачи нужно завершить ввод текста Enter'ом, а не ctrl-d. Иначе сам сайт acmp.ru решение не примет. Если я правильно разобрался в sys.stdin, то это бесконечный ввод, enter его не завершает, а переводит строку

Comment: ctrl-d/ctrl-z обрабатываются терминалом, а не вашей программой (поэтому для разных терминалов - разные комбинации), и является признаком завершения потока ввода. Уж поверьте на слово, это то, что вам нужно для решения этой задачи.

Comment: точнее ctrl+d в Pycharm завершает ввод текста, но для сайта с задачами это видимо не подходит. нужен enter, как мне кажется. с обычным input() на 9 тесте был неверный ответ. ваш способ работает в Pycharm, но на сайте в первом же тесте выдает ошибку "Runtime error". видимо из-за бесконечного ввода

Comment: Значит читаете ввод неправильно `a = [int(x) for x in sys.stdin.read().split()]`

Comment: до этого я вводил `a = list(map(int, sys.stdin.read().split()))`. оба варианта выдают ошибку "Runtime error" в первом тесте. изначально я вводил `a = list(map(int, input().split()))` для проверки решения в целом. тогда он выдает "Wrong answer" на 9 тесте. думаю дело в завершении ввода. в вашем варианте не подходит `enter`. других возможных проблем я не вижу. если интересно - сама задача - https://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=1&id_section=7&id_topic=119&id_problem=736

Comment: Я знаю что это за задача, и у меня она решена вышеописанным способом. Ищите ошибку в другом месте. Например, после stdin.read() у вас в тексте есть еще `input()`, или есть выход за границы списка, или деление на 0. Во всех случаях будет Runtime error.

Comment: О! спасибо, разобрался. действительно небольшой косяк был с моей стороны, ваш способ сработал